# Manage Subscriptions Page says Cannot Connect

Tags: ios, swiftui, subscription, storekit, revenuecat

App Store kept rejecting my app because the Manage Subscriptions Page says `Cannot Connect` when it's run on a Sandbox account. I'm using the [manageSubscriptionsSheet(isPresented:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/managesubscriptionssheet(ispresented:)) API, and I don't know how to fix this.

[image]

There are others dealing with the same issue and everything I found so far is saying it's iOS issue.

I responded to the App Store saying it's an iOS issue and included the following links:

1. [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708331)
2. [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708088)
3. [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252880721)
4. [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251391010)

They replied with the following generic message:

During our review, we found that your app displayed an error message when we tapped on "manage subscription". While we cannot provide technical assistance with the reported issues, we have put together the following resources which discuss common issues seen in apps during review.

To start, please see [Testing a Release Build](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/testing-a-release-build), which gives an overview of how to test your app to minimize the chances of issues occurring during review.

You may also want to review [Designing for Real-World Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WhyNetworkingIsHard/WhyNetworkingIsHard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH13-SW1), as all apps are reviewed on-device and in an environment that replicates real-world use of your app.

Is there a way to fix this? How should I respond back? Also, can I just take out the `Manage Subscription` functionality?

Comment: For anyone else with the same issue, you can just open the "manage subscriptions" link as shown in [Enable Users to Manage Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/handling_subscriptions_billing#3221913)